# Finding the minimal polynomial of an operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let L: V $\rightarrow$ V be a linear operator such that L$^{2}$ + 1$_{V}$ = 0. If V is a real vector space, show that 1$_{V}$ and L are linearly independent and that $\mu_{L}$(t) = t$^{2}$ + 1.

My attempt at a solution: Since L$^{2}$ + 1$_{V}$ = 0 implies L$^{2}$ = -1$_{V}$ and V is real-valued, we have that for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of L, $\lambda^{2}$ = -1 which is not possible in the reals. This implies $\mu$ cannot be a degree 1 polynomial and that $\mu_{L}$(t) = t$^{2}$ - (-1) = t$^{2}$ + 1, as we have just the one zero.

Now my textbook doesn't have any examples of finding the minimal polynomial of an operator like this, is this the approach I should always take? Is this even correct?

And for linear independence, I'm kind of sloppy here:

As L$^{2}$ = -1$_{V}$ and V is real-valued, the only way for $\alpha_{1}$L + $\alpha_{2}$1$_{V}$ to be zero is when $\alpha_{1}$ = $\alpha_{2}$ = 0.

This is more or less intuition-based, as I'm not explicitly saying L is the square root of -1$_{V}$, but it feels obvious to me.

My question isn't so much about the linear independence, just the part about the minimal polynomial. Is this always the approach I take, where I basically just treat the operator as a polynomial itself, find its zeroes and then use these with the factor theorem to find the minimal polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phrasing is rather clumsy. The question is very simple. Since the polynomial $t^2 + 1$ annihilates $L$, the minimal polynomial $\mu_L$ divides $t^2 + 1$ in $\mathbb{R}[t]$. Now $t^2 + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[t]$, hence $\mu_L = t^2 + 1$ (unless it is $1$, which only happens if $\dim V = 0$). If $1_V$ and $L$ were linearly independent, then the degree of $\mu_L$ would be at most $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I think I've just been having trouble thinking in terms of polynomials, especially when using operators. Going from operators to polynomials just seems strange to me for some reason, but I know that means I just need to work with them more. I've reworked my proof to be more clear, thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome. Bonus question: give the simplest possible expression of $L$ as a matrix (i.e. for a good choice of basis).